# Application Verifier vs Gflags

Tags: windows, debugging

I'm trying to debug a heap corruption problem.  I've seen posts referring to gflags and application verifier.  Is there any difference between these two tools, or is the application verifier a pretty UI around the same technology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no much difference between Application verifier and gflags.
Application verifier is UI based tool basically on top of gflags. Both used for dynamic code analysis.